# .NET 5 System.Text.Json configure [FromBody] to avoid deserialisation error with non-string dictionary key

Tags: c#, json, .net, system.text.json, .net-5

I'm migrating a project from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` to `System.Text.Json`. I couldn't do this in .NET Core 3.1 due to [dotnet/runtime#38056](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/38056) as some of my models contain properties of type `IDictionary<int, T>`, something like:

```cs
public class MyClass {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<int, ThingClass> Things { get; set; } 
}
```

In .NET 5 this now works for serialisation, so this works:

```cs
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<MyClass> Get(int id) ...
```

However, when I send data back:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task Update([FromBody] MyClass changes) ...
```

With a body like (note that the key of `"things"` is numbers, not strings}:

```json
{ 
    "id": 789,
    "things": {
        123: { ... },
        456: { ... }
    }
}
```

I get an error:

> Unable to cast object of type `` 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,MyNamespace.ThingClass]' `` to type `` 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.Int32,MyNamespace.ThingClass]' ``.

```
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.IDictionaryOfTKeyTValueConverter`3.Add(TKey key, TValue& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.DictionaryDefaultConverter`3.OnTryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, TCollection& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo`1.ReadJsonAndSetMember(Object obj, ReadStack& state, Utf8JsonReader& reader)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCoreAsObject(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore[TValue](JsonConverter jsonConverter, Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore[TValue](JsonReaderState& readerState, Boolean isFinalBlock, ReadOnlySpan`1 buffer, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, JsonConverter converterBase)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

This looks like something is pre-parsing the body first (and assuming the key is a string) and then the step from `Dictionary<string, ThingClass>` to `IDictionary<int, ThingClass>` fails, but then the keys should *never* have been parsed as `string` in the first place.

What is doing this deserialisation wrong?

How do I configure what `[FromBody]` uses? Why isn't it using the same settings as the deserialisation?

Is this a bug in .NET 5's `System.Text.Json` (it seems way too basic, someone would have spotted it way before this) and if so is there any way around it?

---

**Note:** This question is *not* about whether numeric keys are in the [`RFC8259` standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259) (they aren't). They do work in actual JS and are in lots of JSON in the wild and so do sometimes need to be output and parsed. `System.Text.Json` [claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#dictionary-with-non-string-key) that it supports non-string dictionary keys, I want to get that working. *"Use `NewtonsoftJson`"* or *"you're not spec compliant"* will not be accepted as answers.

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported by `System.Text.Json`. According to the .NET 5.0 [`System.Text.Json` migration docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#json-strings-property-names-and-string-values):

> `System.Text.Json` only accepts property names and string values in double quotes because that format is required by the [RFC 8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259) specification and is the only format considered valid JSON.

Here is the corresponding section of [RFC 8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-4):

> An object structure is represented as a pair of curly brackets
> surrounding zero or more name/value pairs (or members).  A name is a
> string.

The fix for non-string dictionaries which you have linked seems to target version 6.0 of `System.Text.Json` so it seems that if you need to support this scenario you still need to use `Newtonsoft.Json`.

Comment: Cheers, always super helpful to hear exactly which part of an abstract spec a current working application is breaking. I'm currently using Newtonsoft, it works because the JSON works (whether it meets the retroactively applied spec or not), this question is how do I upgrade? Thanks for your time, but this quite specifically does not answer the question.

Comment: @Keith Sorry, missed that you are trying to migrate from Newtonsoft. .NET 5.0 (as written in the linked docs for 5.0) still does not support non-string property names (and non-strings dictionaries). The bug fix link you've added targets `System.Text.Json - 6.0` which will be shipped with .NET 6.0 I assume.

Comment: Hrm , good point, only it's merged into the 5.0 RC code and `Dictionary<int, T>` works now in both serialisation and deserialisation if I call it directly. It seems like `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<int, T>>` works in .NET 5, but doesn't in `[FromBody]`.

Comment: @Keith it [does not](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lBpyTC) for me.

Comment: Woa, that is weird. Manually deserialising does work for my current code, but the `IDictionary` is a sub property of a class that is being parsed. I'll try unpicking that and see if I can get something that either a) works, or b) crashes in the same way your sandbox is.

Comment: @Keith TBH moving to the sub property  [does not change anything](https://dotnetfiddle.net/geiisF). Both on my machine and in the fiddle.

Comment: And right from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#table-of-differences-between-newtonsoftjson-and-systemtextjson): ***Table of differences between Newtonsoft.Json and System.Text.Json**: Allow property names without quotes  ❌ Not supported*.

Comment: @Keith - To confirm what this answer says, JSON with unquoted property names is malformed according to the [standard](https://json.org/) and always have been.  If you upload your JSON to https://jsonlint.com/ or https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ you will get an error.  Json.NET will parse nonquoted property names because it supports this extension to the standard, see [How to enforce quotes on property names on JSON .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53304218/3744182) and [Support "strict mode" for RFC7159 parsing #646](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/646).

Comment: @dbc yes, there's JSON, as in JS object notation that works in JS, and the sub-set-JSON standard that adds restrictions for what I'm sure are good reasons (but I do hate not being able to comment in `.json` config files). Being strictly compliant with any standard is not a concern of my current project, working in browsers is. `NewtonsoftJson` works now, .NET 5 release hype goes "hey `System.Text.Json` is better", this question is how do I get the recommended solution to work in my existing project? "Your project is not compliant with a spec" is not an answer.

Comment: @dbc also, those docs refer to [**string** property names without quotes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#json-strings-property-names-and-string-values), i.e. `{"prop":1}` is fine while `{prop:1}` is bad. In fact it states that [serialising a dictionary with a non-string key is **supported**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#dictionary-with-non-string-key)

Comment: @GuruStron Even weirder - that is _working in my code_! However, I'm passing a load of settings that may change the behaviour from the default (none actually refer to dictionary serialisation though). I'll try changing/removing them and see if I can find which settings mean I'm seeing a different result.

Comment: @Keith - Serializing a dictionary with a non-string key is supported by converting the key to a string.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/twennS.  That's because the JSON standard states that all property names are strings, see https://www.json.org/json-en.html, specifically https://www.json.org/img/object.png. If this is somehow working in your code then somewhere in your code path the JSON is getting preprocessed and normalized.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. An idea - you should create your `Converter` and use it `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(src, new CustomKeyJsonConverterNewton())`. In the example below converter created for `Dictionary<k,v>`, probably it's possible to create a converter just for `k`:

```
    public partial class SerializerNewtonJson
{
    private class CustomKeyJsonConverterNewton : JsonConverter
    {
        private readonly Type[] _types;

        public CustomKeyJsonConverterNewton(params Type[] types)
        {
            _types = types.ToArray();
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JToken t = JToken.FromObject(value);
        
            if (t.Type != JTokenType.Object)
            {
                t.WriteTo(writer);
            }
            else
            {
                JObject o = (JObject) t;
                IList<string> propertyNames = o.Properties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
        
                o.AddFirst(new JProperty("Keys", new JArray(propertyNames)));
        
                o.WriteTo(writer);
            }
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue,
            JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            Type keyType = null;
            Type valueType = null;
            IDictionary result;
            MethodInfo? methodInfo = null;

            if (objectType.IsGenericType)
            {
                keyType = objectType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                // Shold be a way to parse form string to object of target type
                // Here "Parse" method is used, you can use another approach to convert string->value 
                methodInfo = keyType.GetMethod("Parse");
                valueType = objectType.GetGenericArguments()[1];
                Type dictionaryType = null;
                if (objectType == typeof(Dictionary<,>))
                    dictionaryType = typeof(Dictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(keyType, valueType);
                else if (objectType == typeof(ReadOnlyDictionary<,>))
                    dictionaryType = typeof(ReadOnlyDictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(keyType, valueType);
                else if (objectType == typeof(ConcurrentDictionary<,>))
                    dictionaryType = typeof(ConcurrentDictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(keyType, valueType);
                
                if (dictionaryType == null)
                    result = (IDictionary) Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
                else
                    result = (IDictionary) Activator.CreateInstance(dictionaryType);
            }
            else
            {
                result = (IDictionary)Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
            }

            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
                return null;

            int depth = reader.Depth;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
                {
                }
                else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.EndArray)
                {
                    if (reader.Depth == depth)
                        return result;
                }
                else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.EndObject)
                {
                    if (reader.Depth == depth)
                        return result;
                }
                else
                {
                    object key = methodInfo.Invoke(null, new[] {reader.Value});
                    reader.Read();
                    object value = serializer.Deserialize(reader, valueType);
                    result.Add(key, value);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
        
        public override bool CanWrite
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            // !!! instead adding each type of generic dictionary via constructor
            // we try to process all dictionaries here
            if (typeof(IDictionary).IsAssignableFrom(objectType) )
                return true;
            
            var objTypeInterfaces = objectType.GetInterfaces();
            var res = _types.Any(type => type == objectType || objTypeInterfaces.Any(@interface=> @interface == type));
            return res;
        }
    }
}
```